# Bad indentation when pasting into VIM

Tags: python, vim, clipboard

So I'm still pretty new to VIM but I've managed so far. I am using [python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) in my syntax folder. But whenever I paste python code from outside into VIM, the indentation is different. VIM syntax makes a tab, that is 8 char wide, but pasted text is 4 whitespaces. You can see it on this pic:

[image: VIM pasted code]

Is the syntax file wrong? Or should I adjust some settings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may just have vim set to convert spaces to tabs. Try setting:

```
tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
```

in your .vimrc. Also, before you paste, just do

```
:set paste
```

Then insert, paste, then

```
:set nopaste
```

Here is a good writeup on [paste mode](http://blog.ayaz.pk/2008/06/21/paste-mode-pasting-text-and-indenting-it-in-vim/).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already did that. If you don't do it that the indentation is even weirder!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes with vim pasting you can visually select the copied code and press

```
=
```

which will reformat the code to your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` to `4`.

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to help. Still indenting everything. Pasting to anything else produces correct result. `cat <<EOT > file.py` seems like better option.

Answer (score 1):

```
" Correct bad indent while pasting.
nnoremap <Leader>p p=`]
nnoremap <Leader>P P=`]
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.